# Removing extra Tab row delimiter in ssis

Tags: ssis

I am  loading data from table to flat file destination, where my flat file destination is Tab delimited. Actually my query is combination of 3 queries where I merged this 3 queries into into a single query by using temp table.

I have attached my output extract. Actually for data section 1, section 2, I have only 7 columns, where as for section 4 I have 10 columns.

Now, I want to remove the extra tabs from section 1 and section 2 data.

Am Attaching the required output also. how can I remove the extra tabs.

[image: myoutfile]

[image: required format]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pair of options come to mind

1) Concat all your fields into one big string in your derived column transformation and your Flat File Connection Manager now spits out a single column of wide data

2) Add a script task after the data flow, open the file and use a regular expression, possibly a string.Replace would suffice, to strip the trailing values